# Jboss clustering

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I have two jboss servers in  x.x.x.a and x.x.x.b servers and I have same application deployed in both of them. They have 2 application urls with start and stop buttons and status message to consume JMS messages. The two servers are clustered and if one application is started the other url is also showing status as started but both are not consuming.

Please help to start the second application also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jboss clustering works this way only.